# Intuition for divergence of $\arctan \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)$, the angle in the Spiral of Theodorus

Tags: geometry, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

A (UK sixth form; final year of high school) student of mine raised the interesting question of how to prove that the total angle in the Spiral of Theodorus (formed by constructing successive right-angled triangles with hypotenuses of $\sqrt{n}$), diverges.

He identified that this is equivalent to proving the divergence of the series $$\sum_{r=1}^\infty \arctan \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt r}\right)$$ and came up with an interesting proof attempt which didn't conceptually work (although it was very nicely thought of).

The best I could offer by way of intuition is that $\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right) \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$, and the latter series diverges by comparison with $\frac{1}{n}$. But the $\arctan$ value is strictly lesser, so that doesn't convert into a precise proof as far as I can see.

He hasn't been taught formal convergence tests (and it's a while since I was taught them!) although I'm sure he'd be very open to learning. However, I can't shake the feeling there ought to be a nice geometrical demonstration that the spiral does indeed keep winding around the starting point.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than concentrating on the angle, consider the arc length of the spiral.

At the $n$th step, we add a right triangle of base $\sqrt n$ and hypotenuse $\sqrt{n+1}$, with the outer side (of course) of length 1 perpendicular to the base. So we add a new arc to the spiral which must be greater than 1. Hence the arc length at $n$ steps must be greater than $n$. Thus the arc length diverges, and so must the angle.

(FWIW, a decade or so ago, I spent some time trying to come up with a good approximation of $n$ given a total angle of $\theta$. It gets rather messy...).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_of_Theodorus) has some info, including an analytic continuation of the spiral published by Davis in 2001. It also has this nice diagram.

[image: Spiral of Theodorus]

And here's a link to their [SVG version](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9f/Spiral_of_Theodorus.svg). (I'm sure it'd be easy to make a much smaller SVG).

Comment: Ah, this makes sense; just to confirm I'm understanding you correctly, am I right that the arcs you are describing pass through the vertices where the right angles are (and outside the line segments of length 1)?

Comment: @dbmag That's correct. I guess there's some ambiguity: you could just use those line segments themselves as the spiral, but some people like to draw a smooth curve through those vertices, and call that curve the spiral. But my argument works for both versions. ;)

Comment: FWIW, one of my high school mathematics teachers told us that this spiral is a logarithmic spiral. It took me a while to realise that he was very much mistaken. It's a bit disheartening when an otherwise great teacher makes blunders like that.

Comment: An interesting bit of trivia: [Theodorus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodorus_of_Cyrene) gave proofs of the irrationality of the square roots of all the non-square integers up to 17, and 17 is the last number in the first "lap" of the spiral. OTOH, there's not much point proving $\sqrt{18}$ is irrational when you've already done $\sqrt 2$. ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is not "intuition". By MacLaurin expansion at $x=0$ we have

$$\arctan\sqrt{x}= \sqrt{x}+O\left(x^{3/2}\right)$$
Therefore
$$\arctan\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}\sim \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}};\quad n\to\infty$$
So the given series diverges.

**edit**

This is a *rigorous* proof of the divergence

Comment: Isn't that what the OP has already said?

Comment: My first thought reading this is that $\frac{1}{2^n} \sim \frac{1}{n}$ when $n\to\infty$, but $\sum \frac{1}{2^n}$ converges and $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges. Have I misunderstood your notation or reasoning?

Comment: @TobyMak Yes, buy OP doesn't believe it is a real proof

Comment: @dbmag9 Maybe you have to review what asymptotic equivalence means, if you say that $\frac{1}{2^n}\sim\frac{1}{n}$. The limit as $n\to\infty$ of the ratio must be a nonzero constant, and your example is not the case

Comment: @TobyMak I have edited my answer, tho